# Bumblebee with 2 dedicated video cards?

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, intel, bumblebee

So I have a lenovo 510p laptop, with integrated Intel HD 4600 graphics, plus 2 GeForce GT 755M-s, one of which is in the ultrabay and thus is removable. I'm running Lubuntu 13.10.
I use the proprietary nvidia driver (331).

I installed bumblebee, and it seems to be working fine when the removable graphics card isn't present, however if I plug in the ultrabay, strange things happen.

Somehow it seems that the integrated intel card isn't picked up, and I have no idea, what happens actually.

Some logs:

**Optibay VGA taken out:**

```
lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 755M] (rev ff)

sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:c2000000-c23fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)

glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 9.2.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:

optirun glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 755M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 331.20
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.20
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

**Optibay VGA connected:**

```
lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 755M] (rev a1)
07:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 755M] (rev a1)

sudo lshw -c video
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK107M [GeForce GT 755M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:d3000000-d3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK107M [GeForce GT 755M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)

glxinfo | grep OpenGL                                                                                           
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 755M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 331.20
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.20
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:

optirun glxinfo | grep OpenGL
[  379.117608] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.
[  379.117665] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

**So the big question is**: is this normal? 
I never had a machine like before (also never used bumblebee before), so I don't really know, what to expect.

Nevertheless, the situation seems strange, and if possible, I'd like to use the intel card both cases and it would nice not having to remove the second VGA when I want a nicely working linux.
**Is there a way** for example **to completely disable/hide the optibay VGA?** I wouldn't want to use it in linux anyway.